# A set $A \subset [0,1]$ is measurable and $L_1(A)>0$. For function $f(x) = L_1(A \cap [0,x])$ calculate the value of $\int_A f(x) dL_1(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

Take $A \subset [0,1]$ that is measurable and $L_1(A)>0$.

Then take $f(x) = L_1(A \cap [0,x])$, for every $x \in [0,1]$

Calculate $\int_A f(x) dL_1(x)$.

*$L_1 = $ Lebesgue measure.

---

As I understand it:

$$\int_A f(x) dL_1(x) = \int_A \int_{A \cap [0,x]} 1 \ dL_1(x) \ dL_1(x)$$

But I don't understand how to integrate over $A \cap [0,x]$ since it can be not continous (I don't know where A exists and where it doesn't since I only know it's measurable). That problem occurs in both integrals.

I found a problem regarding similar mathematical objects here: [$f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ absolutely continuous, $f' \in \{0,1\}$ (a.e.), $f(0)=0$. Prove that for some measurable subset $A$, $f(x)=m(A \cap (0,x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829508/f-0-1-to-mathbbr-absolutely-continuous-f-in-0-1-a-e-f0). From what I understad, we can assume that every $f$ that is:

- absolutely measurable,
- described over $[0,1]$,
- $f' \in \{0,1 \}$,
- $f(0) = 0$

is equal to: $f(x) = m(A \cap [0,x])$ for our $A$ ($A$ is measurable and $ A \subset [0,1]$) and $x$: ($x \in [0,1]$)

- $A$ is measurable and $ A \subset [0,1]$,
- $x \in [0,1]$.

Maybe in the case stated above it can be argued that $f(x) = m(A \cap [0,x])$ also?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945783/intuitively-obvious-integration-identity?noredirect=1) might be helpful.

Comment: I don't quite see the connection since I don't have any $f(x)$ as described in that question (here is only the function that is itself a measure of the set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a convenient trick based on symmetry you can use to evaluate this integral, but I think a more general approach based on the general [change of variables theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) can also work, which would probably let you compute other related integrals.

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure and define a measure $\mu$ by $\mu(E) = m(A\cap E)$. The problem can be phrased as we want to compute
$$
\int_0^1 \mu([0,x])\,d\mu(x).
$$
Unwrapping the definition and using Fubini's theorem we observe
$$
\int_0^1 \mu([0,x])\,d\mu(x) = \int_0^1\int_0^x\,d\mu(y)\,d\mu(x) = \int_0^1\int_y^1\,d\mu(x)\,d\mu(y) = \int_0^1\mu([y,1])\,d\mu(y).
$$
Therefore (note that $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables),
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \mu([0,x])\,d\mu(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\mu([0,x])+\mu([x,1])\,d\mu(x) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\mu([0,1])\,d\mu(x) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\mu([0,1])^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2}m(A)^2.
\end{align*}
Note, we used that $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$ for every $x$ to say $\mu([0,x]) + \mu([x,1]) = \mu([0,1])$.